# Codeigniter: email only works occasionally

Tags: codeigniter, email

I have a problem with an email contact form. Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
$postdata = $this->input->post();

//email
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from($postdata['email'], $postdata['firstname'] . ' ' . $postdata['lastname']);
$this->email->to('mail@mydomain.com'); 
$this->email->subject('contact form');
$this->email->message($postdata['message']);    

if ($this->email->send())
    {
    $data['status'] = 'success';
    }
else
    {
    $data['status'] = 'error';
    }

?>
```

The strange thing is that it only works occasionally. I just did 10 tests, #2 and #7 came through. `$status` is used in the view file and it's always 'success', so it seems like the script itself works fine.

Comment: Checked spam? Waited long enough?

Comment: Ah dammit, didn't check spam. They're all in there. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest checking your post data, just to be sure: `error_log('$postdata: '.print_r($postdata, true));`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by goldenparrot, the problem is that my generic test emails got caught in the spam filter.